# RecyclerView does not return to the same position after switching activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, itemtouchhelper

I have implemented drag item in the recycler view using ItemTouchHelper class and it works well, but when I switch between activities the item position returns back to its default. I want the recycler view item position to remain the same even when activities are switched.

```
public RecyclerViewItemTouchHelper(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    super(ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN |
            ItemTouchHelper.START | ItemTouchHelper.END, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT);
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView;
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
    int fromPosition = viewHolder.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();
    int toPosition = target.getAbsoluteAdapterPosition();

    Collections.swap(MainActivity.dataArrayList, fromPosition, toPosition);

    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemMoved(fromPosition, toPosition);

    return false;
}
```